# What's the best practice building unique component IDs using Catberry Framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frameworks, isomorphic-javascript

Catberry has a requirement for components – all their IDs must be unique.

What's the best practice for building unique IDs when you have a complicated hierarchy of nested components?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way for building unique identifiers for nested components is:

```
<parent-component­-id>:<child-component­-name>:<entity-­id>.
```

`entity-id` is optional and used in case you have a list of items or something like that.

It’s very easy to have an ID of the component in your `render` method using `this.$context.attributes.id`.

For example, you have a component that renders a list of items. Its name is `cat-list` with ID `some-list`. Then nested components with name `cat-list-item` have IDs:

```
some-list:list-item:1
some-list:list-item:2
some-list:list-item:3
...
some-list:list-item:N
```

If you have more nested components like `cat-author` for each item then they have IDs:

```
some-list:list-item:1:author
some-list:list-item:2:author
...
some-list:list-item:N:author
```

So, if you use this rule you will have unique identifiers for all components on the page.